# Many digest mismatches in debug.log, timeouts, read repairs

Tags: cassandra, timeout

I am trying to understand the cause of many very short timeouts in my Cassandra cluster(8 nodes, version 3.11.5).
[image]
The graph shows the following metric:

```
org:apache:cassandra:metrics:clientrequest:.*:timeouts:oneminuterate
```

The timeouts are so short that the users of the application do not notice them. I fear, however, that as the load increases, the timeouts will become more and longer.

nodetool netstats output:

```
Mode: NORMAL
Not sending any streams.
Read Repair Statistics:
Attempted: 12870150
Mismatch (Blocking): 817794
Mismatch (Background): 186667
Pool Name                    Active   Pending      Completed   Dropped
Large messages                  n/a         0       63077962        15
Small messages                  n/a         0     3019143378        10
Gossip messages                 n/a         0       25434157      3623
```

Looks like too many read repairs for me.

In addition, read repair exceptions occur from time to time:

```
"loglevel":"ERROR","message":"Exception in thread Thread[ReadRepairStage:143,5,main]\norg.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Operation timed out - received only 1 responses.
```

I see a lot of "digest mismatch" messages in the debug log.I know that these messages are not bad at all, but the amount of messages is huge. If I have understood correctly, these messages mean that the checksum of the requested data does not match.
This means a lot of read repairs, right?

I have tried to find out in the metrics on which tables the read repairs are executed and have identified these.These tables are repaired weekly with Cassandra reaper. Also, all these tables use LWTs which I am not sure if we are using correctly.

Now to my assumption: Since the cluster obviously wants to do a lot of read repairs at the time when something is to be read, there seems to be a certain inconsistency at these times. Since regular repairs are carried out, there is not much more that can be checked from the operation side?

I am grateful for all suggestions.

**edit:**

```
Pool Name                         Active   Pending      Completed   Blocked  All time blocked
    ReadStage                              0         0     2328235507         0                 0
    MiscStage                              0         0              0         0                 0
    CompactionExecutor                     0         0       11132722         0                 0
    MutationStage                          0         0      479557615         0                 0
    MemtableReclaimMemory                  0         0          26341         0                 0
    PendingRangeCalculator                 0         0             18         0                 0
    GossipStage                            0         0       23864150         0                 0
    SecondaryIndexManagement               0         0              0         0                 0
    HintsDispatcher                        0         0             79         0                 0
    RequestResponseStage                   0         0     1628853410         0                 0
    Native-Transport-Requests              0         0     1211484433         0                 0
    ReadRepairStage                        0         0       56071751         0                 0
    CounterMutationStage                   0         0              0         0                 0
    MigrationStage                         0         0             55         0                 0
    MemtablePostFlush                      0         0          42223         0                 0
    PerDiskMemtableFlushWriter_0           0         0          26331         0                 0
    ValidationExecutor                     0         0          17160         0                 0
    Sampler                                0         0              0         0                 0
    MemtableFlushWriter                    0         0          26341         0                 0
    InternalResponseStage                  0         0          19335         0                 0
    ViewMutationStage                      0         0              0         0                 0
    AntiEntropyStage                       0         0          70678         0                 0
    CacheCleanupExecutor                   0         0              0         0                 0
    
    Message type           Dropped
    READ                         0
    RANGE_SLICE                  0
    _TRACE                       0
    HINT                         0
    MUTATION                     0
    COUNTER_MUTATION             0
    BATCH_STORE                  0
    BATCH_REMOVE                 0
    REQUEST_RESPONSE             0
    PAGED_RANGE                  0
    READ_REPAIR                  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your assumptions are incorrect. Seeing a lot of digest mismatches in the logs is very bad.

The mismatch is detected by the coordinator when data returned by replicas are not the same so read-repairs are triggered to synchronise the replicas. This isn't normal behaviour.

For replicas to be out-of-sync with each other means that data is missing because one (or more) replica(s) missed writes. The missed writes (dropped mutations) occur because the nodes cannot keep up with the app traffic.

The symptoms you described in your post indicate that your cluster is overloaded. This is the reason for the timeouts you are seeing including the read-repair exceptions and the high number of dropped messages.

You need to either (a) throttle the traffic from your application(s), or (b) increase the capacity of your cluster by adding more nodes. Cheers!

Comment: But how can the cluster be overloaded if the hardware is bored? The CPU never goes over 10%, the NVME disks barely do iops and the network is not really busy at 50Mbps on a 10G interface. Besides, we added three new nodes 3 months ago and the behaviour did not change at all.
In addition: The cluster currently makes just under 5k op/s. I did a benchmark before we went live and got around 100k op/s out of the cluster.

Comment: None of that changes the fact that the nodes are dropping mutations (writes). That's the only way replicas get out of sync. Cheers!

Comment: Okayy got it. 
But how can you do capacity planning if hardware utilisation and op/s in the cluster have no significance?

Comment: It indicates to me that you're not looking at the right place. You need to investigate further as to why nodes become unresponsive. Notice in the `nodetool netstats` output you posted that there are thousands of dropped gossip messages. You need to figure out why that's happening. Cheers!

Comment: Maybe you can point me to the right place if prometheus hardware metrics are not enough to see where the bottleneck is.
I also added the nodetool tpstats output to my post with 0 dropped mutations.

Comment: Output from nodetool netstats/tpstats/cfhistogram etc only show me the symptoms of the problem and if it really is an overload of the cluster, the cause should be the hardware? Since this is barely under load according to our hardware metrics, I wonder where the right point is to look. Each node holds 50GB of data, which is not very much.